# Ajax post submit fails in ie9/8

Tags: jquery, .net, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain

I'm trying to make an ajax post for a form which works in chrome, firefox and latest ie. In ie9/8 it appears to fail with a 500 error.

The ajax post is cross domain, i'm using https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest to make cross domain requests (ajax get appears to work in ie9/ie8).

This is a .NET project, if that helps any. I did read as a possible solution was to add:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

at the top, but that hasn't fixed anything.

Here's a post of my sample code:

```
            var submitEmailMe = $("button#emailme_form_submit");

            $(submitEmailMe).unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {

                if ($('#email_form').parsley().validate()) {
                    emailMeSubmit();
                }

                var emailBtnState = $(this);
                emailBtnState.prop('disabled',true);
                window.setTimeout(function(){ 
                    emailBtnState.prop('disabled',false);
                },5000);

                e.preventDefault();
            });


            function emailMeSubmit() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "http://www.externallink/EmailRetailer",
                    data: $("#email_form").serialize(),
                    success: function( response ) {

                        $('#email_form').fadeOut(function() {
                            $('.thanks').fadeIn();
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey so I figured this issue out in case anyone else has the same issue as me.

So in the documentation for https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest they specify to set the contentType: 'text/plain' however this still wasn't working.

What I found was that the form actually submitted to ie8 and ie9 cross-origin, using that xdomainrequest plugin, if I changed it from **'POST'** to **'GET'**.

This might not be the most elegant solution but it worked.